# Function to create a specific cell value format for daily use

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am not an excel guru by any means, therefore would like support in creating a function for the following:

We have a column for category trees in the following format in our sheet:

**Example category cell format**- a/b/c/d (there is no defined limit to the tree, it could also be a/b/c/d/e)

**Expected cell result** - a,a/b,a/b/c,a/b/c/d

This will be used on a daily basis as our team keeps creating new category trees every day. So will need to create a macro for this.

This is my first time here. Hope I was able to explain this clearly

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1419v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange and Super User are not free code writing services but, in the interests of "being nice", the information below sets out in a form of pseudo-code the kind of program structure that you could use in VBA to convert your input into your required output.

There are two tasks that this structure performs:

1. The input is split into its component "words" (the parts separated by the / character). The result of this task should be an array (or list) of "words"
2. The array of words is repeatedly traversed starting from the first to build the output. In each traversal successive "words" are separated in the output with a / character. The first traversal stops after the first word, the second traversal stops after the second word has been added, the third traversal after the third word has been added, etc. At the end of each traversal the / character is NOT used as a separator but a comma (,) is used instead. No comma is used at the end of the final traversal.

​

```
      ​ '(TASK 1)​
       ​Read input string from worksheet​
       ​Initialise number of "word"s found as zero
       ​Initialise current "word" to null string  
       ​For each character in input string​
           ​If character is / Then
                ​'(End of current "word" found)
                ​Increase by 1 number of words found
                ​Add current "word" to array of words
                ​Start new "word" as null string
           ​Else
                ​Add character to current "word"
           ​End If​
       ​Next character
       ​'(Don't forget to add current "word" to array of words)
       ​Increase by 1 number of words found
       ​Add current "word" to array of words
                ​
       ​'(Now have an array of "words" with known number of words in it)
   ​
       ​'(TASK 2)
       ​'(Creation of output string involves use of an inner loop nested within an outer loop)
       '(Inner loop performs a traversal, outer loop repeats the traversals and
       'increases the number of words involved in each traversal)​
       ​Initialise output string as null string​
       ​'(Outer loop)
       ​For each "word" in array of words​
           ​'(Inner loop - traverse from first "word" of array to current outer loop "word")   
           ​For each "word" from first to current outer loop "word"
               ​If current inner loop "word" is not the first in array of "words"
               ​    Add / separator to output string
               ​End If
               ​Add current inner loop word to output string
           ​Next inner loop "word"​
           If current outer loop "word" is not last in array of "words"
               ​Add , separator to output string
           ​End If​
       ​Next outer loop "word"​
       ​Write output string to worksheet
```

You will need to work out how to represent the above as VBA variables and code. If you have any questions you can ask them in the comments.

A couple of hints that you may find helpful are: the variable length array of "words" can be built using the `REDIM PRESERVE` statement; the default in VBA is to start indexing an array at zero so the the first element of array X is X(0), the second is X(1), etc but you can change this to start indexing from 1 using the `OPTION BASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSE formula in `B1` :

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1&"/","/","@",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))+1)))))-1))
```

[image]